# How to avoid jquery ui tooltip to occur in child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am tying to include tooltip only in parent div but not in its child div.

Here is jquery ui tooltip:

```
$(function () {
    $("#parent_div").tooltip();
});
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="parent_div" title="Hello Tooltip">
    parent div contents
    <div id="child_div" onMouseOver="show_list();" onMouseOut="hide_list();" title="">
    child div contents
    </div>
    parent div contents
</div>
```

`title=""` (giving blank to title property) in child_div is creating some problem. After hover on child_div it disables the tooltip from parent_div also.

You can see and test the problem [HERE](http://browsersgames.comze.com/n/).

Please give me some solution keeping in view that onMouseOver and onMouseOut events should not be disable because I am using them in child_div for some other purpose.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: pls check what u written on `hide_list` function. that may even stop working mouseover for parent_div 's too.

Comment: Nope: I have also tried this by removing `onMouseOver="show_list();"` and `onMouseOut="hide_list();"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to **disable** `tooltip` when you are with `mouseover` child, an **enable** when `mouseleave` child.

```
  $("#child_div").mouseover(function(){
      $("#parent_div").tooltip('disable');
  })

  $("#child_div").mouseleave(function(){
      $("#parent_div").tooltip('enable');
  })
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("#parent_div").tooltip();
  
  $("#child_div").mouseover(function(){
      $("#parent_div").tooltip('disable');
  })
  
  $("#child_div").mouseleave(function(){
      $("#parent_div").tooltip('enable');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="parent_div" title="Hello Tooltip">
    parent div contents
    <div id="child_div" title="">
    child div contents
    </div>
    parent div contents
</div>
```

Comment: thank you adricadar. I solved the problem with some edition to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try replace this:

```
<div id="child_div" onMouseOver="show_list();" onMouseOut="hide_list();" title="">
```

with this

```
<div id="child_div" onMouseOver="show_list();" onMouseOut="hide_list();">
```

Comment: Please read my question. It will not do anything fine. In this scene tooltip of its parent div will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I hope everyone can get advantage of it.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#parent_div").tooltip();
  
  $("#child_div").mouseover(function(){
      $("#parent_div").tooltip('disable');
  })
  
  $("#child_div").mouseleave(function(){
      $("#parent_div").tooltip('enable');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="parent_div" title="Hello Tooltip">
    parent div contents
    <div id="child_div" title="">
    child div contents
    </div>
    parent div contents
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for me is this:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    content: function(){
        return $(this).not("#MY_ELEMENT *[title]").attr('title');
    }
});
```